# Pass jQuery event to default on-eventhandler

Tags: events, jquery-plugins, event-handling, jquery

I've written a function to call the default `jQuery.fn.on`-handler, after a given number of fired events. Now I stuck, because the original `event` will not passed to the function, any ideas how to improve this?

```
;(function ($) {
    var oldOn = $.fn.on,
        i = 0;
    $.fn.on = function () {
        var args = arguments,
            j = args.length;

        for (var last in args);

        while (j--) {
            if ($.isFunction(args[j]) && !isNaN(args[last])) {
                var oldFn = args[j],
                    after = args[last];
                args[j] = function () {
                    i++;
                    if (i === after) {
                        oldFn.call();
                        i = 0;
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        if (!isNaN(args[last])) delete args[last];
        return oldOn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(jQuery);

// call the plugin and fire the `fn` after each 20 mousemoves
$(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
    console.log(e); // undefined
}, 20);
```

As you can see, will the following work without problems:

```
var oldOn = $.fn.on;
$.fn.on = function () {
    return oldOn.apply(this, arguments);
};

$(document).on('click', function(e){
    console.log(e) // jQuery.Event
});
```

Where's the mistake, how can i get this to work?

**Update**

I got it much simpler now: https://github.com/yckart/jquery.unevent.js

Comment: what do you expect this line `for (var last in args);` to do?

Comment: @Hogan It seems to me, that this is the easiest way to get the last item from arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the arguments from your callback wrapper function to the original callback function.

```
args[j] = function (*HERE*) {
  i++;
  if (i === after) {
    oldFn.call(*TO HERE*);
    i = 0;
  }
};
```

Try replacing `oldFn.call();` with `oldFn.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments));` to carry them over (and keeping up jQuery's `this`).

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/QFyhX/

Comment: In my fiddle, yup, since it was just meant as an example (and as a separate function to jQuery#on). It works when you just do the parameter passing thing in your code though. I've also updated the fiddle.

Comment: Yeah, got it already therefore i removed my comment :P My way: `return oldOn.apply(this, (isNaN(num) ? arguments : args));` http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/hmn3B/

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
for (var last in args);
```

should be

```
var last = args[args.length-1];
```

Comment: that would be nice :) however it doesn't work http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/hmn3B/0 btw: `Length ` > `length` ;)